# Role Object pattern question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am looking at a paper done by Martin Fowler called [Dealing With Roles](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf). In it, Fowler breaks out three basic strategies for dealing with roles for a Person in an organization (ie, Employee, Engineer, Manager, Salesman) which include Role Subtyping, Role Object, and Role Relationships.

Having been written in 1997 it is certainly old, and being a "working draft" it also has some errors that otherwise wouldn't be there. I am confused going over an example of Role Object he goes through, and have included a my c# interpretation of some of his java code below.

I have three questions:
(1) there's a lot of type identification being done with strings that seems like it should be replaceable with generics, but I can't get a handle on how to do so yet. How would you implement this code using generics?
(2) JobRole is in the code as the string name for a type but it is not specifically defined with the rest of the code. I can't tell if this is a base class for PersonRole or not. What is the definition of JobRole? Does the unit test look like a correct example of the pattern's usage?
(3) Does anyone have any links  towards a more recent implementation and example of using a Role Object?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
public class PersonWithRoles : Person
{
    private readonly IList<PersonRole> _roles = new List<PersonRole>();

    public static PersonWithRoles CreatePersonWithRoles(string identifierName) {
        ...
    }

    public void AddRole(PersonRole role) { _roles.Add(role); }

    public PersonRole RoleOf(string typeName) { return _roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasType(typeName)); }
}

public class PersonRole
{
    public virtual bool HasType(string typeName) { return false; }
}

public class Salesman : PersonRole
{
    public override bool HasType(string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.Equals("Salesman", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return true;
        if (typeName.Equals("JobRole", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) return true;

        return base.HasType(typeName);
    }

    public int NumberOfSales { get; set; }

}

[TestFixture]
public class RoleUsageTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test() {
        var p = PersonWithRoles.CreatePersonWithRoles("Ted");
        var s = new Salesman();
        p.AddRole(s);

        var tedSales = (Salesman) p.RoleOf("Salesman");
        tedSales.NumberOfSales = 50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am under the belief that these types of applications are good candidates for the use of the **decorator design pattern** in which there is a Person base class, and then each role extends that base class. The base class has no declarations of permissions -- only the roles classes that extend person should.

Sorry to be vague, but I hope you get what I'm trying to describe.

```
class programmer {
 name ...
 email ...
 seat location ...
}

class html_coder extends programmer {
 canCodeHTML ...
}

class script_coder extends programmer {
 canCodeHTML ...
 canCodeJavascript ...
}

class senior_developer extends programmer {
 canCodeHTML ...
 canCodeJavascript ...
 canAccessDatabase ...
 canEditProjectArchitectureFiles ...
 canWearTennisShoesToWork...
}
```

these all extend the programmer base class... notice that the programmer class does not declare rights... just properties

Comment: I *think* so. Could you scratch out some sample code or give me a link that shows it? Cheers

Comment: from the same paper by Fowler: "A useful variation on this pattern is to make the role objects decorators of the core object. This
means that a client who uses only the features of employee person can deal with a single object and not need to know about the use of role objects. The cost is that when ever the interface of person changes, all the roles need to be updated. See [Bäumer et al] for more details on how to do this."

Comment: Here's the [link to Baumer's work](http://hillside.net/plop/plop97/Proceedings/riehle.pdf) that Fowler references. It outlines a pattern composed of (3) major participants; Using your example there would be an abstract Programmer that defines the interface for a programmer as well as the interface for managing roles. Then there is a ProgrammerCore which implements both the Programmer interface and the role amangement. Finally there is a ProgrammerRole which decorates an instance of ProgrammerCore. HtmlCoderRole and SeniorDevRole are subclasses of the ProgrammerRole. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Generics in c# can help make a neater implementation
2. `JobRole` is a sub-type of `PersonRole`, and a super-type for a specific jobs

I'd still like to see examples of usage, as one of Fowler's points about this pattern is that the typing flexibility comes at the expense of a two step usage pattern. Implementing this using a Decorator pattern does not change this. For example, to work with a Person in the Role of Salesman, first you need to get an instance of a person and then find the role of Salesman.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
public class Person
{
    public FullName FullName  { get; set; }
    public IList<IRole> Roles { get; private set; }

    public Person(FullName fullName) => FullName = fullName;

    public IRole GetRoleOf<T>() where T: IRole => 
        Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasType(typeof(T)));
    public void AddRole(IRole role)    => Roles.Add(role);
    public bool RemoveRole(IRole role) => Roles.Remove(role);
```

}

```
public interface IRole
{
    bool HasType(Type type);
}

public abstract class Role : IRole
{
    public virtual bool HasType(Type type) { return false; }
}

// Base type for any type of role for a person.
public class PersonRole : Role
{
    public override bool HasType(Type type) => type.Equals(typeof(PersonRole));
}

// Base type for any type of role for a person.
public class JobRole : Role
{
    public override bool HasType(Type type) 
    {
        if (type.Equals(GetType())) return true;
        return base.HasType(type);
    }
}

// Behavior specific to a salesman
public class Salesman : JobRole, ISalesman
{
    public override bool HasType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.Equals(GetType())) return true;
        return base.HasType(type);
    }

    public int NumberOfSales { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class JobRoleTests : BaseTestFixture
{
    private PersonEx _person;

    protected override void OnFixtureSetUp() 
    {
        _person = new PersonEx(new OneNameFullName("schmuck"));
        // can be a Salesman
        _person.AddRole(new Salesman());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Salesman_CanGet() 
    {
        var salesman = _person.GetRoleOf<Salesman>() as Salesman;
        Assert.That(salesman, Is.Not.Null);
        salesman.NumberOfSales = 50;
        Assert.That(salesman.NumberOfSales, Is.EqualTo(50));
    }
}
```